# Kivy: Pixel density aware media

Tags: kivy

Native android SDK supports media files differentiation with `drawable-x`, where x is one of ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high) paths for media.

Is there a way to control which media should be used for which kind of pixel-density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the the dpi, density, resolution etc. through the `kivy.metrics` module, which on android uses the values reported by the system. Once you have that, you can easily choose a different image source depending on its value, though I don't think there is a standard property or widget to point at.

I'm not really famililar with the mechanism and advantages of the normal java method here, but it would probably be quite easy to make something very similar in kivy. For instance, you could easily make your own image widget subclass that chooses a specific image of a certain size depending on the pixel density.